# Bootstrap Columns inside Row different renderings

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have multiple rows that I would like to line up all in the same fashion.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="#"><div class="img-circle index circle partner-circle box-shad"></div></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">
      <a href="#"><h2 class="partner-heading">Stuff </h2></a>
      <hr />
      <p class="lead">This is some text</p>
  </div>
</div> <!-- row -->
```

But the `h2` text is not lining up properly in relation to the other elements as shown in this picture:

[image]

[The site is HERE](http://californiafootgolfclub.com/dev/partners/) if you would like to see it live. Can you help me figure out why the styling is inconsistent between the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change (in your style.css)

```
.circle1, .circle3 {
    margin: 39px 0 41px;
}
```

to this

```
.circle {
    margin: 39px 0 41px;
}
```

then all the Images Line up with the rightside content

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/ With this Plugin you can realtime look at your Document. I used this to find it.

Comment: I use Firebug, but couldn't find this when I was debugging. Thank you for helping and the suggestion